# kube service domain name not working, but clusterIP does work with Jupyter Enterprise Gateway

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-kernel

I have a Jupyter notebook setup in the `jupyter` namespace on a kubernetes cluster, and Jupyter Enterprise Gateway setup in the `enterprise-gateway` namespace as a Service in the same cluster.

If I configure the notebook to connect to the `enterprise-gateway` service using the clusterIP it works fine.

```
--gateway-url=http://172.20.186.249:8888
```

but if I switch to using the service domain name the notebook receives a 503 Connection Refused error

```
--gateway-url=http://enterprise-gateway.enterprise-gateway.svc.cluster.local:8888
```

When I use busybox check to check the kubernetes dns, the domain resolves as expected.

```
kubectl -n default exec -ti busybox nslookup enterprise-gateway.enterprise-gateway
kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
Server:    172.20.0.10
Address 1: 172.20.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      enterprise-gateway.enterprise-gateway
Address 1: 172.20.186.249 enterprise-gateway.enterprise-gateway.svc.cluster.local
```

How do I get the domain name to work?

The Service config for the JEG looks like this...

```
kubectl describe svc enterprise-gateway --namespace enterprise-gateway
Name:                     enterprise-gateway
Namespace:                enterprise-gateway
Labels:                   app=enterprise-gateway
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          chart=enterprise-gateway-2.6.0
                          component=enterprise-gateway
                          heritage=Helm
                          release=enterprise-gateway
Annotations:              meta.helm.sh/release-name: enterprise-gateway
                          meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: enterprise-gateway
Selector:                 app=enterprise-gateway
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       172.20.250.15
IPs:                      172.20.250.15
Port:                     http  8888/TCP
TargetPort:               8888/TCP
NodePort:                 http  31366/TCP
Endpoints:                10.1.16.136:8888,10.1.2.228:8888,10.1.30.90:8888
Port:                     response  8877/TCP
TargetPort:               8877/TCP
NodePort:                 response  31201/TCP
Endpoints:                10.1.16.136:8877,10.1.2.228:8877,10.1.30.90:8877
Session Affinity:         ClientIP
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Comment: You need an ingress controller, have you tried already ?

Comment: take a look at https://jupyter-enterprise-gateway.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0.0/kernel-kubernetes.html#setting-up-a-kubernetes-ingress-for-use-with-enterprise-gateway if you need further info im up to assist you

Comment: @jmvcollaborator thanks for looking into this. An Ingress is for exposing a Service to clients external to the cluster. That is not what I am doing. I have a Service that an application in the same cluster needs to connect to. A Service should be sufficient for this https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#creating-a-service

Comment: As mentioned in the question the accessing the Service via the clusterIP does work, it is access via the service name in the DNS that is not working.

Comment: clusterip is for local access only ip:port you should add maybe a load balancer service and link the external ip to the DNS

Comment: I am doing local access. The client application is in a Pod in the same cluster, that is why using clusterIP works. According to this page the application should also be able to use the service dns which resolves to the clusterIP.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i dont know where to start i have a bunch of findings. I will start with the eye catcher one, i have a working test project i can share later on and i have to elaborate more in this answer if needed.

**Step1**

1- I see a mismatch on your IPs. The DNS lookup did not resolved the service DNS to the correct IP.
Address 1: 172.20.186.249 is different than IP:                 172.20.250.15

To debug DNS:

1. kubectl exec "YOURPODNAME" cat /etc/resolv.conf
2. Verify that a search path and a name server are set up correctly

   nameserver 10.96.0.10
   search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
   options ndots:5
3. check if the kubedns/coredns pods are running

   kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system
   NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
   ....
   kube-dns-86f4d74b45-2qkfd               3/3       Running   232        133d
   kube-proxy-b2frq                        1/1       Running   0          15m
   ...

If the pod is running, there might be something wrong with the global DNS service

```
kubectl get svc --namespace=kube-system
NAME      TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE kube-dns ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>   53/UDP,53/TCP
```

You might also need to check whether DNS endpoints are exposed:

```
kubectl get ep kube-dns --namespace=kube-system
NAME       ENDPOINTS                     AGE
kube-dns   172.17.0.5:53,172.17.0.5:53   133d
```

These debugging actions will usually indicate the problem with your DNS configuration, or it will simply show you that a DNS add-on should be enabled in your cluster configuration.

**Step 2**

When using busybox to check the kubernetes dns
This seems incorrect when looking Address 1: 172.20.186.249 im expecting to get an IP 10.X.X.X
Install dnsutils on the pod as pointed below

1. kubectl exec --stdin --tty "YOURPODNAME" -- apt update &&  sudo
   apt-get -y install dnsutils
2. kubectl exec -it "YOURPODNAME" -- /bin/bash
3. Inside the pod and again (weird) run apt-get install dnsutils
4. Stay inside the pod and run nslookup "YOURSERVICENAME" you will get
   an IP and a Name(DNS).
   **Check this IP since it needs to match with the IP of the service description.**
5. kubectl describe svc "YOURSERVICENAME", **the IP should be the same as #4**
6. What you must see:

[image: Ip Matching, Dns resolving]

**Step 3**

1. Once you have Step #2 solved you will be able to use the service
   name(FQDN) returned in Step 2 item #4

To be continued...

Comment: thanks, I'll allocate the bounty to you. I've been occupied with some higher priority tasks, so will be coming back to this issue soon

Comment: ok i will stay tuned